# Python - str.match for each string in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use str.match to match a phrase exactly, but for each word in each row's string. I want to return the row's index number for the correct row, which is why I'm using str.match instead of regex.

I want to return the index for the row that contains exactly 'FL', not 'FLORIDA'. The problem with using str.contains though, is that it returns to me the index of the row with 'FLORIDA'.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex in FL','ten'],['Bob in FLORIDA','five'],['Will in GA','three']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

df.index[df['Name'].str.contains('FL')]
df.index[df['Name'].str.match('FL')]
```

Here's what the dataframe looks like:

```
    Name             Age
0   Alex in FL       ten
1   Bob in FLORIDA   five
2   Will in GA       three
```

The output should be returning the index of row 0:
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df.Name.str.contains(r'\bFL\b', regex=True)]
```

OR

```
df[['FL' in i for i in df.Name.str.split('\s')]]
```

Output:

```
         Name  Age
0  Alex in FL  ten
```

Answer (score 3):

Use contains with word boundaries:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex in FL','ten'],['Bob in FLORIDA','five'],['Will in GA','three']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])

print(df.index[df['Name'].str.contains(r'\bFL\b')])
```

**Output**

```
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) say that it's matching Regex with the expression ("FL" in your case). Since "FLORIDA" does contain that substring, it does match.

One way you could do this would be to match instead for " FL " (padded with space) but you would also need to pad each of the values with spaces as well (for when "FL" is the end of the string).